# How to center divs on css?

Tags: html, css

Well , I want to center my banner text, and image as the psd, but however I tried with `margin: 0 auto, margin: 0 auto 0 auto,`  and other things , but it didn't work even if I use tag center, how can I fix it ?  when I want to see my html to a larger page it looks bad, and not centered, I don't know what to do someone can help me.

css:-

```
.banner{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #505a78;
}

.banner p{
    display: block;
}

.banner_text{
    color: #fff;
    padding: 150px;
}

.banner_text h1,
.banner_text h1 span{
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat Black';
}

.banner_text .banner_wrap{
    margin:0 auto 0 auto; 
    width:auto;
}

.banner_text p{
    color: #a5abbb;
    font-family: 'Montserrat Light';
}

.banner_text p > span{
    display: block;
}

.banner_text a {
    margin-top: 25px;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 62px;
    padding: 4px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #7cdf95;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Montserrat Black';
text-align: center;
}

.banner_text img {
    width: 75%;
    margin-top: -275px;
}
```

html:-

```
  <section class="banner">
         <div class="banner_text">
            <div class="banner_wrap">
               <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span>consectetur adipiscing elit</span></h1>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo.<span> Cum sociis  natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur</span></p>
               <a href="#">button</a>
               <img src="img/16251331_10210478393849069_2072529108_o.png" alt="">
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
```

[psd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGH5M.jpg)
[my_html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzRJL.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Try adding:**

```
.banner_text .banner_wrap{
    margin:0 auto 0 auto; 
    width:50%;
}
```

The `width:50%;` will center the div in the middle of the page, if that is what you want !

Answer (score 0):

You set the div center this way

```
margin: auto;
width: 50%;
```

If you don't set the width or set the width to 100% then the div will never center.

If you want to center the text inside the div then use

```
text-align: center
```

If you want to center an image then use

```
display: block;
 margin: auto;
```